# NSCollection error: Cannot create NSData from object NSImage

Tags: objective-c, nscollectionview

I have a NSCollectionView with 3 objects, two NSTextFields and one NSImageView. I am getting my data by letting the user select a folder and then reading the contents of that folder. I pull the file name, path and sniff for type (file/folder) and if it is a folder get its icon (using NSWorkspace) or if it is a file its image. (these should all be image files, there's a filter in place to check).

Anyway, my bindings seem to be right as the text fields are getting populated but the NSImageView is not and I get this error message when I try to pass the NSImage to my model.

```
//loop through the data
for (NSString* thisItemKey in fileManagerResults) { 

    //get our item data dictionary
    NSDictionary* thisItemData = [fileManagerResults objectForKey:thisItemKey];
    //get the item name
    NSString* itemName = [thisItemData objectForKey:@"Item Name"];

    //filter for hidden files 
    NSString *value = [itemName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    if(![value isEqualToString:@"."]) {

        //make a new imageModel
        ImageModel* thisImageModel = [[ImageModel alloc] init];

        //add some data to our image model
        thisImageModel.itemName = itemName; 
        thisImageModel.itemType = [thisItemData objectForKey:@"Item Type"];
        thisImageModel.itemPath = [thisItemData objectForKey:@"Item Path"];
        thisImageModel.creationDate = [thisItemData objectForKey:@"Creation Date"];

        //get the file icon
        NSImage* theItemIcon;
        NSString* itemType = [thisItemData objectForKey:@"Item Type"];
        if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"Directory"]) { 
            theItemIcon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[thisItemData objectForKey:@"Item Path"]];

        } else { 
            theItemIcon = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[thisItemData objectForKey:@"Item Path"]];
        }

        thisImageModel.itemIcon = theItemIcon; 

        [tempArray addObject:thisImageModel]; 



    }

    //pass the data to our controller
    [self setControllerArray:tempArray];


}
```

Whenever I run this though I get the following error message:

```
Cannot create NSData from object NSImage 0x16074e10 Size={450, 350} Reps=(
NSBitmapImageRep 0x16075ba0 Size={450, 350} ColorSpace=NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace BPS=8 BPP=24 Pixels=450x350 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=0
) of class NSImage
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to correct this...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I was selecting data for my binding and not value in IB. Yes, I sit here with great shame. : D

Comment: Just did the very same thing — d'oh!